# Panning on pyplot imshow

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, scroll, pyqt

I would like to know how to scroll (up/down, left/right) while keeping a viewport size constant using pyplot imshow.

My idea is to take a large numpy array (image) but I only want to show a small part of it at a time. It would be perfect if i could add some panning hand cursor in order to push up/down/right/left my viewport.

Any tips?

Comment: Matplotlib provides zooming and panning by default. What exactly is the problem of using it?

Comment: I know that matplotlib provides such functionalities. The point is that when using imshow with the "large array" i have not the detail that I need in terms of zoom that's why i need to set a viewport smaller than the large array and scroll along it horizontally and vertically.

Comment: And because of that, i should start by displaying one of these regions (e.g viewport) avoiding to show the large image without zoom thus avoiding the user to select a region to zoom

Comment: You can set the limits with `ax.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)` and `ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)` or with `ax.axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])` first and then use the panning tool.

Answer (score 1):

To turn my comments into an answer:

Matplotlib provides the necessary tools to pan the plot by default. This is detailed in the [Interactive navigation article](https://matplotlib.org/users/navigation_toolbar.html).

> [image] 
>   The Pan/Zoom button
>   This button has two modes: pan and zoom. Click the toolbar button to activate panning and zooming, then put your mouse somewhere over an axes. Press the left mouse button and hold it to pan the figure, dragging it to a new position. When you release it, the data under the point where you pressed will be moved to the point where you released. If you press ‘x’ or ‘y’ while panning the motion will be constrained to the x or y axis, respectively. [...] You can use the modifier keys ‘x’, ‘y’ or ‘CONTROL’ to constrain the zoom to the x axis, the y axis, or aspect ratio preserve, respectively.

[image]

Limiting the axes is possible e.g. via `ax.set_xlim(xmin,xmax)` and `ax.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)` or via `ax.axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.random.rand(600,800)

plt.imshow(im)
plt.gca().axis([200,300,150,250])

plt.show()
```